# Membership of professional societies/associations for electrical and electronic engineers

Tags: electrical-engineering, licensure

Membership of which professional organizations for electrical and electronic engineers are recognized globally?

Comment: MIEE arguably tops. MIEEE arguably tops by other arguers. Many country recognitions are "good enough" eg IPENZ from NZ. But, fwiw, you do not NEED any such if you are not spending government money or looking to work for a company that demands that "stuffed shirt" be part of the kit. If you build a reputation you can be "recognised" anywhere and be employable by almost all organisations worth working for. .

Comment: @RussellMcMahon Your abbrevations seem to me a little bit unclear. Maybe your comment could be converted to (longer) answer.

Comment: Make that: [**MIEEE**](https://www.ieee.org/index.html) (the pretenders :-) ) of [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Institute_of_Electrical_and_Electronics_Engineers) and      [**MIET**](http://www.theiet.org/)  nee [MIEE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Institution_of_Electrical_Engineers)  now [thusly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Institution_of_Engineering_and_Technology_(professional_society))

Comment: @RussellMcMahon: In Australia, it is absolutely necessary to be registered on a professional register (such as NPER or RPEQ) to do high-level engineering work. A stirling-silver reputation isn't enough. For example, all engineering designs in Queensland must be signed off by an RPEQ, who is then legally liable for the design. Since RPEQ now requires CPEng from Engineers Australia (excepting grandfathered applicants), being RPEQ practically requires MIEAust and CPEng.

Comment: @Li-aungYip I'm probably covered by grandfathering clauses, should they exist, in the NZ system, but it's of minimal interest to me now. As I noted, if I'd stayed in corporate employ it would be different. I've now been "self employed" for almost as long as in my prior 'lifetime'. I have BE and ME (4 year gap between, both university of Auckland) - both gained prior to Washington accord so technically possible that neither my be recognised internationally.

Answer (score 2):

From an Australian perspective:

1. I have a Bachelor's degree in electrical engineering.
2. I am a graduate member of Engineers Australia.
3. I am a member of Institute of Electrical and Electronic Engineers.

#### My degree

My bachelor's degree in engineering was received from a university whose engineering course is accredited by Engineers Australia.

Because the course is accredited by Engineers Australia, and because Engineers Australia is a signatory of the [Washington Accord](http://www.ieagreements.org/Washington-Accord/), my engineering degree is also recognised by [all other signatories to the Washington Accord](http://www.ieagreements.org/Washington-Accord/signatories.cfm). **This means my engineering degree is recognised globally.**

#### Engineers Australia

Since I hold a bachelor's degree in engineering, and I work in Australia, I am eligible to be a member of Engineers Australia.

Membership of this organisation is specific to my country, and is tied to some legislation which is also specific to my country.

For example, Australian law requires one to be a Engineers Australia *Chartered Professional Engineer* (CPEng) to perform certain duties. This doesn't immediately transfer to other countries, where you need to attain the local equivalent of CPEng to meet that country's requirements.

Similarly the other local Australian registers, such as the *Registered Professional Engineer, Queensland* (RPEQ) and *National Professional Engineers Register* (NPER) are tied to Australian laws.

Where equivalents to CPEng, RPEQ, NPER exist overseas, there **may** be a *mutual recognition agreement* which automatically grants the foreign version if you have the Australian version, and vice versa. See the Engineers Australia document [Supporting the Professional Mobility of Engineers in Australia and the United States.](https://www.engineersaustralia.org.au/sites/default/files/shado/Member%20Services/International/ea_trade.pdf)

#### The IEEE

Since I hold a bachelor's degree in electrical engineering, I am eligible to be a member of the IEEE. **This is an internationally recognised membership** - my IEEE membership stays the same no matter what country I am living in.

However, my membership of the IEEE doesn't mean much in Australia. It does not grant any special privileges or duties in Australia, and IEEE is not relevant to any Australian laws. Membership of Engineers Australia is considered much more important than IEEE.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose, structure and the value proposition of each of these organizations differ between been each other yet recognize each other credentials.

For example if once credentials are US base and has a need to acquire similar credentials for Engineers Australia, then one would have to submit the necessary paper work to [Engineers Australia](https://www.engineersaustralia.org.au/) for evaluation and acceptance. Under the auspicious of the [**Washington Accord**](http://www.ieagreements.org/Washington-Accord/Washington-Accord-Overview.pdf) most credentials are cross listed. I can confirm that my US based Electrical Engineering credentials were accepted by Engineering Australia in accordance with the Washington Accord. Therefore I believe that my credentials will be accepted by any professional engineering organization that is part of the [Washington Accord](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Washington_Accord).

Therefore if your electrical engineering credentials are accepted by one body who is a part of the Washington Accord then your electrical engineering credentials are almost certain to be accepted by any other body that is part of the Washington Accord.

---

The following are the signatory accreditation bodies of the Washington Accord.

- Australia - ([Engineers Australia](https://www.engineersaustralia.org.au/), 1989)
- Canada - ([Engineers Canada](https://www.engineerscanada.ca/), 1989)
- Taiwan - ([Institute of Engineering Education Taiwan](http://www.ieet.org.tw/en/), 2007)
- Hong Kong - ([The Hong Kong Institution of Engineers](http://www.hkie.org.hk/eng/homepage.asp), 1995)
- India - ([National Board of Accreditation](http://www.nbaind.org/views/Home.aspx), 2014)
- Ireland - ([Engineers Ireland](https://www.engineersireland.ie/home.aspx), 1989)
- Japan - (Japan Accreditation Board for Engineering Education, 2005)
- Korea - ([Accreditation Board for Engineering Education of Korea](http://www.abeek.or.kr/htmls_kr/en/index.jsp), 2007)
- Malaysia - (Board of Engineers Malaysia, 2009)
- New Zealand - ([Institution of Professional Engineers New Zealand, 1989](http://www.ipenz.org.nz/ipenz/))
- Russia - (Russian Association for Engineering Education, 2012)
- Singapore - (Institution of Engineers Singapore, 2006)
- South Africa - ([Engineering Council of South Africa,](https://www.ecsa.co.za/default.aspx) 1999)
- Sri Lanka - ([Institution of Engineers, Sri Lanka, 2014](http://www.iesl.lk/))
- Turkey - (MÜDEK, 2011)
- United Kingdom - ([Engineering Council UK](http://www.engc.org.uk/), 1989)
- United States - ([ABET](http://www.abet.org/), 1989)

There are few post here in engineering stackexchange related to similar discussion.

---

**References**:

- [What is the process of transferring an engineering license from the United States to Germany?](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/6/what-is-the-process-of-transferring-an-engineering-license-from-the-united-state)
- [Washington Accord](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Washington_Accord)
- [Sydney Accord](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sydney_Accord)
- [International Professional Engineers Agreement, IPEA](http://www.ieagreements.org/Agreement-Constitutions-Version-1.pdf)

Comment: I no longer know what I am deemed to be, nor especially care. I worked for over 20 years for NZ's largest company and obtained and maintained a professional engineering qualification (then termed "Registered Engineer"). Then the national professional engineering body got the attention of a ranking politician and in due course obtained an entirely new set of requirements with suitable hoops and obstacles to keep everyone happy.

Comment: ....  Had I remained in corporate work, maintaining such would just have been 'cost of doing business' and accepted and paid for by my employer in terms of both make-work lost hours required to meet semi-arbitrary requirements plus actual fees. In my subsequent private industry activities the "qualification"  would be nice to have to illuminate one's slate but has probably minimal if any value wrt NZ clients and none whatsoever in any of my related Asian activities. So, where that leaves me in the systems eyes exactly I know not.

Comment: ... My degrees were attained long ago, the continuous on the job training continues, as may be evident :-).