# How important is an ABET-accredited Engineering Degree in the EU (like Germany) or other countries that is not in North America?

Tags: chemical-engineering, licensure

I have an option to either attend **Middle East Technical University - North Cyprus Campus** (non-ABET accredited) or **Mapua University** (ABET accredited) in the Philippines to study Chemical Engineering as an undergraduate. I would personally prefer to study in (METU NCC) than in Mapua, but have been reticent due to the Chemical Engineering program there not being ABET accredited. I have a feeling, however, that ABET accreditation mainly pertains to engineers in the United States. *How important is the ABET accreditation if one wants to pursue a job in the EU or other countries NOT in North America after their bachelors in engineering?* *How will this affect my job prospects?* If you have any experience in this, please don't hesitate to share them. There seems to be a lack or contradictory information in the internet regarding this matter. Thank you so much!

Comment: What is  **Middle East Technical University - North Cyprus Campus** programs accreditation?

Comment: I'm not sure if it has accreditation, but they do have the list of Alumni and their field of study. Looking at it, it seems that they have a lot of undergrads abroad and getting hired at British Petrol, Pepsi Co., and other big brands just after their bachelors or pursuing higher education in Europe or in America [here](https://alumni.ncc.metu.edu.tr/mezun_harita/index.php?lng=en). Looking at the curriculum of their ChemEng undergraduate study, it easily shows to me how comprehensive and "difficult" the studies are going to be, look [here](https://ncc.metu.edu.tr/chme/curriculum).

Comment: See above @MahendraGunawardena

Answer (score 2):

One of benefits of accreditation is when dealing with governments bodies. When one has to get education credential verified such in case EU having a international recognized credentials make the process less painful. I have a ABET accredited credentials and found it value when I have had to get my qualification verified and accepted by government bodies and Professional Engineering bodies other than the domicile.

Also take a look at the [Washington Accord](http://www.ieagreements.org/accords/washington/). This will give alternative view points.

### References:

- [What is the process of transferring an engineering license from the United States to Germany?](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/6/what-is-the-process-of-transferring-an-engineering-license-from-the-united-state?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)
- [Which US states require a bachelors in Engineering to become licensed?](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/a/7244/110)

Comment: they told me this," We have just met the minimum graudation numbers to complete the application for the Cyprus campus and will not last long to get approved. However i must also say that  ABET accreditation is one of the certification methods for competency. It is not a substitute for "recognition". Engineering programs at METU NCC are not yet accredited by ABET, but it does not mean that the diploma issued by METU NCC is not recognized. METU NCC diploma, issued by METU, is recognized all around the world. In the process of ABET (once obtained), we do not need any other accreditation."

Comment: furthermore, they also mentioned: "Of course, your diploma will be recognized and allow you to work in Turkey. You do not need to pass any Board Exam." METU NCC's mother branch in Turkey is one of the best in that country. If I study and work in the Philippines, entry-salary for engineers would be around $646.75 per month. THAT IS SO LITTLE!!!! I COULD work abroad after studying in the Philippines, but that is a whole other research I have to do and be informed about in the internet. :( @MahendraGunawardena